# Plotting with various Manipulate options

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, graphics

I am trying to plot with the following code

```
B = -2; A = 1;
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], x[0] == 1, 
Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}, {R}];
coll = {};
Table[pp = 
ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[a][t]], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}];
pts = pp[[1, 1]];
AppendTo[
coll, {a, #[[1]]} & /@ 
pts[[First@Cases[pp[[1]], Point[x__] :> x, -1]]]];, {a, 0.0, 5, 
0.01}];
lp = ListPlot[Join @@ coll, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red];
Manipulate[
Column[{ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[par][t]], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], 
Show[lp, Graphics[{Gray, Line[{{par, 0}, {par, 4}}]}]]}], {par, 
0.0, 5, 0.01}]
```

I want to manipulate for more than one parameter, In the code I have to then replace `R` with any other parameter I want to manipulate with. I want to manipulate for all parameters `A,B,R` with a range from, say `0` to `100`. The solution part goes without error, but the plot part starting at `coll={}` gives errors even though I tried to increase the number of parameters. I tried for one extra manipulating parameter and amended the code as

```
coll = {};
Table[pp = 
ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[a][b][t]], {t, 0, 20}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}];
pts = pp[[1, 1]];
AppendTo[
coll, {a, b, #[[1]]} & /@ 
pts[[First@Cases[pp[[1]], Point[x__] :> x, -1]]]];, {a, 0.0, 5, 
0.01}, {b, 0.0, 5, 0.01}];
lp = ListPlot[Join @@ coll, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red];
Manipulate[
Column[{ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[par1][par2][t]], {t, 0, 20}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], 
Show[lp, 
Graphics[{Gray, 
  Line[{{par1, 0}, {par1, 4}, {par2, 0}, {par2, 4}}]}]]}], {par1, 
0.0, 5, 0.01}, {par2, 0.0, 5, 0.01}]
```

It gives error messages.

Comment: What errors? I can't reproduce any error messages. Have you tried reducing your example to narrow the problem down?

Comment: @Kuba Yes the code works, but problem occurs when I am trying to put more than one parameters in `Manipulate`, as i mentioned in the second code above.

Comment: The working code also gives error messages when I give the antisymmetric initial conditions `x[0]=1,y[0]=-1` instead of `x[0]=1,y[0]=0`, how to get around this error?

Comment: You have a lot going on in the code so it's hard to parse but the second section produces errors even before hitting the `Manipulate` part.

Comment: @JānisŠmits Right. The second part however does not return errors, if instead we choose the initial conditions as `x[0]=1,y[0]=0` or `x[0]=0,y[0]=1` or with `-1`. and a single `Manipulate` parameter, as mentioned in the first code. But the error seems to pop up somehow when choosing antisymmetric initial conditions `x[0]=1,y[0]=-1` or `x[0]=-1,y[0]=1`.

Comment: I am unsure what this line does: `AppendTo[
coll, {a, b, #[[1]]} & /@ 
pts[[First@Cases[pp[[1]], Point[x__] :> x, -1]]]];, {a, 0.0, 5, 
0.01}, {b, 0.0, 5, 0.01}];` But one error you made is not redefining the `s` function to have multiple parameters. Here I am sweeping values of A and B:

Comment: `R = 1.
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
     B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], x[0] == 1, 
    Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
    y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}, {A, B}];
derp = Table[
   pp = ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[a, b][t]], {t, 0, 20}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}], {a, 0, 5, 1.}, {b, 0., 5., 
    1.}];`